# Which way should I choose to make the class thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a code which is as below

```
class classA {

   int sum = 0;
   void recursiveMethodA {
       sum = sum +1; // For simplicity
   }
}
```

Basically I am doing some operation in a recursive method which runs lets say 10 times and changing state at class level. But this class is not thread safe.

Now in order to make it thread safe I am thinking of a below option.

```
class class B {
    // Public exposed method
    public void methodB {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.recursiveMethodA();
    }
}
```

My logic is that since I am creating object of class A inside a method of class B, it is created on stack instead of heap and hence it is thread safe.

Is this logic correct? Please suggest alternate options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My logic is that since I am creating object of class A inside a method of class B, it is created on stack instead of heap and hence it is thread safe.

Your logic and/or terminology are not correct.  In fact, the instance of `ClassA` is in the heap.  All regular Java objects are created in the heap!

**Your code is actually thread-safe**, but the correct explanation is as follows:

1. The object is created, and the only reference to it is assigned to a local variable.
2. By inspection, no other thread can ever see that variable.
3. By inspection, the object reference is never passed to another thread; i.e. it is not *published*.
4. The points 1., 2., and 3. mean that the object is *thread confined*<sup>1</sup> for its entire lifetime.
5. Since the object is thread confined, it is not necessary to consider thread-safety.

---

It is not sufficient to say (just) that a local variable is used:

- There are scenarios where another thread can see the value of a local variable; e.g. if a lambda or inner method closure is created and passed to another thread.
- It is also necessary to consider that the value in the variable could be passed to another thread.

Finalization and reference processing will be done on another thread.  However, this should NOT present a thread-safety concern.  (The JLS spec takes care of finalization, and the javadocs for `Reference` take care of references.  In both cases, there is a *happens before* at the appropriate points.)

---

<sup>1 - This is a fancy way of saying that no other thread can ever see it the object and its reference.</sup>

---

> Do you mean classA is thread safe by itself?

No. It is not thread safe by itself. It is thread safe in this particular context. Or more to the point, thread safety is moot in this context ... because the instance is thread confined.

> Shouldn't I define the class as thread safe in all the contexts? I don't know how tomorrow it can be used?

That is up to you!

But consider this: a large number of standard Java classes are NOT thread-safe ... by design.   Indeed the classic case is `StringBuilder` which is the non-thread-safe reimplementation of `StringBuffer`.  Others are most of the collection types in `java.util`!

Basically, you have two choices:

- Make a class inherently thread-safe, and accept that this comes with runtime overheads.
- Make a class inherently non-thread-safe, and make sure that you only use it ways that deal with this appropriately.  (One way is to thread confine the instances.  Another is to use some form of external synchronization.)

Comment: No.  It is not thread safe by itself.  It is thread safe in this particular context.  Or more to the point, thread safety is moot in this context ... because the *instance* is thread confined.

Comment: Thanks, But shouldn't I define the class as thread safe in all the contexts? I don't know how tomorrow it can be used?

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way to have a threadsafe function is put keyword "synchronized"

```
synchronized public void method() {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Is the above approach correct or not? I dont want to make it synchronized.